# Avoid data for being inserted into new rows in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have saved a source code .ccp type file under column 'file' in file_details table in a mysql database. It is done not by using a program but by directly inserting through localhost/phpmyadmin interface. The type of the data field is BLOB. Then by accessing saved codes I am calculating the number of spaces of each source codes and I want to insert the values to the database column called 'spaces' in the same table. Here I have given the query that I used.

```
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        Statement count_to_db=conn.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT prog_num,file FROM file_details";

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

       while (rs.next()) {


            String file_content = rs.getString("file");

            CalculatingSpaces calSpaces = new CalculatingSpaces();
            String num_of_Spaces= calSpaces.CalculatingSpaces(rs, pw, file_content);
            int spaces=Integer.parseInt(num_of_Spaces);

           String space_query="INSERT INTO file_details(spaces) VALUES ('"+spaces+"')";
           count_to_db.executeUpdate(space_query);


        }
```

But when I am inserting the spaces they are inserted to a new row but not for the same row where I have uploaded the BLOB files. Is there any way to insert the number of spaces in-front of the BLOB files which spaces related to.

PS : So the problem is Can't I insert data column by column to a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're adding your table row for the first time, you'll have to use the SQL **INSERT** command.

If you want to update an existent row, you have to use the SQL **UPDATE** command.

Don't forget that you need to know which row(s) you want to **UPDATE**, so you'll also need to define a way to uniquely identify your rows (aka the **Primary Key**).

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html for details

Comment: Thanks for replying Leo. Got it.. Will do this and check.